# Default selected option in combo box in Spring MVC Form(JSP)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

```
 Design a form(<spring:form></spring:form>) in JSP using Spring MVC architecture
```

From Controller Enum.values bind in model attribute

Look the code what i am using to bind the list of value of combo and default selected value.

```
  m.addAttribute("questTypes", Enum.values());

  m.addAttribute("defsel", Enum.Value1.getName());
```

Then on JSP page write this code

```
   <form:select path="otquestion.otQuestionId" class="combobox required" style="float:left;" id="selectQuestid">
   <form:option label="Select Question Type..." value=""></form:option>
   <form:options items="${questTypes}" selected="${defsel}" itemLabel="name"  itemValue="value"></form:options>
  </form:select>
```

Finally list is came but default selection of combo is not working. Please help

Comment: Check http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/73245-form-select-tag-chose-one-option-as-selected

Comment: I am already go through on forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/73245-form-select-tag-chose-one-‌​option‌​-as-selected , but not getting any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer by following bind the value of path="otquestion.otQuestionId".
In  otquestion object otQuestionId member variable set the value and return that object with the help of model object.